# Error while generating a signed APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, everytime I try to generate a signed apk this error comes and it won't let me finish generating signed apk:

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows: ... android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    } }
```

...

Here is the **app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gmail.andre00nogueira.feelproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.wonderkiln:blurkit:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'

} apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the **project gradle**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: couldy ou show use your app gradle file?

Comment: can you post your gradle code?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Edited!

Comment: @kdblue Edited!

Comment: Normally this error comes associated with a lint infrigment, did you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: your question itslef is the answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in app gradle inside android{}

```
lintOptions { 
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually as to do with the method you use to generate the signed APK, if you use another method to generate the signed APK you will be able to generate a signed APK.
Hope it helps, good luck!